# excel formula to strip html

Tags: excel

I want to strip all the html away from the left and right of the textual value:

I have this...
`<option value="41">GECommonUI</option>`

I want to get this...
`GECommonUI`

Comment: In VBA or a worksheet-function?

Comment: as an excel sheet function not vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys this is a simple set of string functions. as i am not up to speed on excel string functions this is a pain for me to figure out...

in a programing language this would go somethign like 
mid(start, length) to get the value from the full html string- the trick is to get the length as the start possition minus the lenth of th ending html lenght)

mid( pos(">")+2, len(string)-pos(">") )

Answer (score 2):

in excel
select all
open replace (ctrl+f)
replace `<*>`
with nothing

or use perl regex
$line = "This is some **text** with HTML  and words";
$line =~ s/<(.*?)>//gi;

Comment: I don't know why my above post does not display the asterisk between <>. replace accepts wild cards. not sure what you mean by literal. excel atleast works on the example you posted.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was looking for, but thanks. I learned that the replace accepts wild cards! who knew?

Answer (score 1):

Set a reference to MS Forms 2.0 to use the DataObject object.

```
Public Function StripHTML(sInput As String) As String

    Dim rTemp As Range
    Dim oData As DataObject

    Set oData = New DataObject
    oData.SetText "<html><style>br{mso-data-placement:same-cell;}</style>" & sInput & "</html>"
    oData.PutInClipboard

    Set rTemp = Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Range("a1")
    rTemp.Parent.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
    StripHTML = rTemp.Text

    rTemp.Parent.Parent.Close False
    Set rTemp = Nothing
    Set oData = Nothing

End Function
```

See http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/02/23/html-in-cells-ii/ for more info.

Comment: +1, but I don't think that's exactly what the OP was looking for. I think @kacalapy wants to strip out the HTML, not convert it to valid formatting.

Comment: Converting it to valid formatting is just a side effect.  Because the function returns the Text property of the Range object, the formatting won't be relevant.  It will however remove the html tags as it converts it.

Answer (score 1):

You can download an Excel file with a working user defined function =stripHTML() on the page below. The file has a working example and notes. This will solve your problem. Please note, you will have to allow macros on this Excel document for the function to work.

http://jfrancisconsulting.com/how-to-strip-html-tags-in-excel/

How is my function different?

Most functions I found did a good job of doing a global find and replace to delete all HTML tags that are enclosed in brackets <>.

However this deletes certain line breaks which causes the end result to look a smashed blob of text. I modified an existing function to add back line spaces so the end result keeps appropriate line breaks.

Secondly, the global HTML replaces attributes in brackets only <> All HTML special character notations will remain. Ex. instead of an ampersand &, you'll be left with the HTML version, &. To solve this problem, I inserted 87 replace lines to replace all HTML notations with the characters.

```
Function StripHTML(cell As Range) As String

Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = CreateObject(“vbscript.regexp”)
Dim sInput As String
Dim sOut As String
sInput = cell.Text

sInput = Replace(sInput, “\x0D\x0A”, Chr(10))
sInput = Replace(sInput, “\x00″, Chr(10))

‘replace HTML breaks and end of paragraphs with line breaks
sInput = Replace(sInput, “</P>”, Chr(10) & Chr(10))
sInput = Replace(sInput, “<BR>”, Chr(10))

‘replace bullets with dashes
sInput = Replace(sInput, “<li>”, “-”)

‘add back all of the special characters
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ndash;”, “–”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&mdash;”, “—”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&iexcl;”, “¡”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&iquest;”, “¿”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&quot;”, “”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ldquo;”, ““”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&rdquo;”, “””)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “”, “‘”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&lsquo;”, “‘”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&rsquo;”, “’”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&laquo;”, “«”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&raquo;”, “»”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&nbsp;”, ” “)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&amp;”, “&”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&cent;”, “¢”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&copy;”, “©”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&divide;”, “÷”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&gt;”, “>”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&lt;”, “<”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&micro;”, “µ”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&middot;”, “·”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&para;”, “¶”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&plusmn;”, “±”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&euro;”, “€”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&pound;”, “£”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&reg;”, “®”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&sect;”, “§”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&trade;”, “™”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&yen;”, “¥”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&aacute;”, “á”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Aacute;”, “Á”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&agrave;”, “à”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Agrave;”, “À”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&acirc;”, “â”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Acirc;”, “Â”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&aring;”, “å”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Aring;”, “Å”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&atilde;”, “ã”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Atilde;”, “Ã”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&auml;”, “ä”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Auml;”, “Ä”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&aelig;”, “æ”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&AElig;”, “Æ”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ccedil;”, “ç”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Ccedil;”, “Ç”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&eacute;”, “é”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Eacute;”, “É”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&egrave;”, “è”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Egrave;”, “È”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ecirc;”, “ê”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Ecirc;”, “Ê”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&euml;”, “ë”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Euml;”, “Ë”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&iacute;”, “í”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Iacute;”, “Í”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&igrave;”, “ì”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Igrave;”, “Ì”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&icirc;”, “î”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Icirc;”, “Î”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&iuml;”, “ï”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Iuml;”, “Ï”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ntilde;”, “ñ”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Ntilde;”, “Ñ”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&oacute;”, “ó”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Oacute;”, “Ó”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ograve;”, “ò”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Ograve;”, “Ò”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ocirc;”, “ô”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Ocirc;”, “Ô”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&oslash;”, “ø”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Oslash;”, “Ø”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&otilde;”, “õ”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Otilde;”, “Õ”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ouml;”, “ö”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Ouml;”, “Ö”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&szlig;”, “ß”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&uacute;”, “ú”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Uacute;”, “Ú”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ugrave;”, “ù”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Ugrave;”, “Ù”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&ucirc;”, “û”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Ucirc;”, “Û”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&uuml;”, “ü”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&Uuml;”, “Ü”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “&yuml;”, “ÿ”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “”, “´”)
sInput = Replace(sInput, “”, “`”)

‘replace all the remaining HTML Tags
With RegEx
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = True
.MultiLine = True
.Pattern = “<[^>]+>” ‘Regular Expression for HTML Tags.

End With
sOut = RegEx.Replace(sInput, “”)
StripHTML = sOut
Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: -1 For not posting your function. If your link breaks then the knowledge is lost.

Comment: The above mentioned link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You can try [VBScripts Regular Expression Support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html).

http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscriptexample.html