# How can I use excel Replace <*> in excel vba like in excel? (regular expressions)

Tags: regex, vba, excel

If you want to delete html tags in excel one way is to use the replace function. I search for "<*>" and replace it by "". So I just delete every html tag. Excel VBA also has a replace function but it is far more stupid. If I write:

```
temp2 = Replace(temp2, "<*>", "")
```

It doesn't interpret "< * >" as a regular expression. It only replace 1:1 the string "<*>". How can I use the replace function in VBA like I do in Excel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [excel formula to strip html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135046/excel-formula-to-strip-html)

Comment: There's also the ability to use regular expressions in vba. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: If you would have recorded a macro, you would have got your answer... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search and replace all cells in the active sheet, you need to use something like:

```
Cells.Replace What:="<*>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Note that you can indicate the cell directly in the beginning: `Cells(2,1).` (to only replace in the A2 cell.

Comment: yes thumb up ;) problem is my question is marked as dublicat but the other similiar question doesn't have your good answere ;)

Comment: Your question is not marked as a duplicate. At least at this moment.